# How do I track down which program generates keypresses?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keystrokes

"Enter Key" gets pressed often without me pressing it. So 
there has to be a program that runs in the background and does this, how do I find out which one does this?

One common suspect is `AutoHotKey`. I exited autohotkey and still had the same problem. Is there a way to find the culprit out?

Comment: To confirm your suspicions, you should try booting windows in [safe mode](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+boot+safe+mode+windows+10&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS780US780&oq=how+to+boot+safe+mode+windows+10&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.6136j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and see if the problem persists. If it persists, you can rule out a keyboard hardware issue by disabling the keyboard (preferably while still in safe mode) in device manager and seeing if the problem persists. Last but not least, it would help to have a decent antivirus solution installed to try and rule out the scenario of a computer virus.

Comment: Are you sure the process for AHK is dead? Is the problem OS global? I mean, does it appear in all applications?

Comment: Yes, AHK is dead and still persists. And the problem is OS global, keypress is happening regardless of whichever program is currently focused. I could literally see `Enter` being pressed when I work in `Sublime`, `Notepad`, `Matlab`, `Visual Studio` and what not..!

And I couldn't observe any particular pattern or frequency of the keypresses, if I reboot, it doesn't happen immediately, making it even harder to detect which application is triggering this.

Comment: @BennettYeo Ahh...! I will try disabling the keyboard and see if that's happening, that should narrow down this problem.

Comment: I'm using `Carnac` to find out when a keypress happens, but it doesn't show me which enter it is, the one from the keypad or the main RET? Is there anything I can do to find out which `Enter` is pressed?